# Combine Multiple Byte Arrays Into One PDF Document

Tags: android

I have an array of byte[] PNGs and I am attempting to combine them into one PDF Document, which I can then export, how could I go about doing this?

I have looked into using PrintedPdfDocument, yet still can't figure it out, is there a better way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "byte[] images"? Are they in PNG format? JPEG? Something else?

Comment: They are PNGs, my apologies

Comment: Use iText or similar libraries. `PrintedPdfDocument` is for printing a PDF, not creating one. If your objective is to print these images, you could use the Android printing framework.